# How can I make eclipse gracefully shutdown dropwizard when I debug?

Tags: eclipse, dropwizard

I am experimenting with Dropwizard (https://github.com/robertkuhar/dropwiz_get_start, https://github.com/robertkuhar/dropwiz_mongo_demo ) and am impressed with how easy it is to integrate with my IDE.  To start my dropwizard app, I simply find the class with the main method and "Debug As...Java Application" and I'm on my way.  Stopping the application is equally simple, just click the red "Terminate" button from the Debug view.  I noticed, however, that I don't make it to the breakpoints in the stop() method of my Managed classes when I stop it in this manner.

How do I get Dropwizard to go through graceful shutdown when its running directly in eclipse's Debugger?

```
@Override
public void run( BlogConfiguration configuration, Environment environment ) throws Exception {
    ...
    MongoManaged mongoManaged = new MongoManaged( mongo );
    environment.manage( mongoManaged );
    ...
}
```

Breakpoints in the stop() of MongoManage never get hit.

```
public class MongoManaged implements Managed {
    private final MongoClient mongo;

    public MongoManaged( MongoClient mongo ) {
        this.mongo = mongo;
    }

    @Override
    public void start() throws Exception {
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() throws Exception {
        if ( mongo != null ) {
            mongo.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How is this downvoted?  Geez.  Tough crowd.

Answer (score 0):

Does it help if you use this java feature?

```
// In case vm shutdown
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        // what should be closed if forced shudown
        // ....

        LOG.info(String.format("--- End of ShutDownHook (%s) ---", APPLICATION_NAME));
    }
});
```

Just add this before first breakpoint.

Comment: Does it help? What is your observation?

In my experience, eclipse kills the process in such a way that shutdown hooks are skipped because of https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=38016.